# Can "glade" and "mist" go together?

Tags: word-usage

Can I say "a glade in the mist", meaning a spot where there is no mist or where the mist is not dense?

Answer (score 2):

A *glade* is a treeless area in a forest. A "glade in the mist" would be a treeless area in a forest that is in the mist.

If you want to talk a mist-less patch in a misty area, you could talk about a break in the mist, an opening in the mist, or a void in the mist.

Comment: What about a gleam in the mist?

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛовцкий, a "gleam" is a brightly lit spot. To me if you said you saw "a gleam in the mist" I'd guess there was something shiny a little ways away so that you couldn't see what the shiny thing was through the mist, but you could still see some light reflected from it.

Comment: Thank you, @The Photon.  You have helped me a lot.  From the words you suggest I choose "break". I need it for the following quatrain:

Comment: I have heard those lies before 
about breaks in the dusky mist. 
I despaired, and therefore 
I'm a desperate optimist.